# Processing: Cube rotating stay in one place while moving

Tags: rotation, processing

In the Processing program, I have to make a cube to move in place where the cube moves when pressing lowercase x for counterclockwise of x axis, or pressing capital X for clockwise of x axis, and pressing lowercase y for counterclockwise of y axis, or pressing capital Y for clockwise of y axis, and pressing lowercase z for counterclockwise of z axis, and pressing capital Z for for clockwise for z axis. The problem is that the cube moves out of place, but it does rotate. How do I rotate, but not move out of place? Please help check this code. The code works however it moves out of place. Also, it spins on the first time the button is pressed. How do I fix that?

```
float theta = 0;
void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  fill(127, 127);
  String s1 = "Press x for counterclockwise of x axis, X for clockwise of x axis"; 
  String s2 = "Press y for counterclockwise of y axis, Y for clockwise of y axis ";
  String s3 = "Press z for counterclockwise of z axis, Z for for clockwise for z axis";
  text(s1, 0, width/2 + 100);
  text(s2, 0, width/2 + 125);
  text(s3, 0, width/2 + 150);
  // if(pressLowX() == true) 
  // cubeBox(.5, .5, .5);
  pressButtons();
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  cubeBox(.5, .5, .5);
  popMatrix();
}


void cubeBox(float x, float y, float z) {
  translate(x, y, z);
  rotate(theta);
  beginShape(QUADS);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  vertex(100, 100, 100);
  vertex(-100, 100, 100);
  vertex(-100, -100, 100);
  vertex(100, -100, 100);

  fill(255, 255, 0);
  vertex(-100, -100, -100);
  vertex(100, -100, -100);
  vertex(100, 100, -100);
  vertex(-100, 100, -100);

  fill(0, 255, 0);
  vertex(100, 100, 100);
  vertex(100, -100, 100);
  vertex(100, -100, -100);
  vertex(100, 100, -100);

  fill(0, 255, 255);
  vertex(-100, -100, 100);
  vertex(-100, -100, -100);
  vertex(-100, 100, -100);
  vertex(-100, 100, 100);

  fill(0, 0, 255);
  vertex(-100, -100, 100);
  vertex(-100, -100, -100);
  vertex(100, -100, -100);
  vertex(100, -100, 100);

  fill(255, 0, 255);
  vertex(100, 100, 100);
  vertex(-100, 100, 100);
  vertex(-100, 100, -100);
  vertex(100, 100, -100);
  // rotate(-theta);
  // translate(-x, -y, -z); 
  endShape(CLOSE);
}

void pressButtons() {
  if (key == 'x') { 
    theta = theta - .05;
    rotateX(radians(0));
  } else if (key == 'X') {
    theta = theta + .05;
    rotateX(radians(0));
  } else if (key == 'y') {
    theta = theta - .05;
    rotateY(radians(90));
  } else if (key == 'Y') {
    theta = theta + .05;
    rotateY(radians(90));
  } else if (key == 'z') {
    theta = theta - .05;
    rotateZ(radians(60));
  } else if (key == 'Z') {
    theta = theta + .05;
    rotateZ(radians(60));
  }
}
```

Comment: Do your translation always before rotation. If C is the position of the object (translation so far), R is the rotation matrix, then the transformation of a point p is p' = R (p - C) + C. As you see, the point is first translated to the origin (translation is undone) then rotated and then translated again.

Answer (score 1):

To rotate a geometry in place, the rotation has to be applied to the geometry before the translation:

```
P' = translation * rotation * P
```

This means you have to do the the instructions in this order:

e.g.

```
  translate(x, y, z);
  rotateX(theta);
```

The issue is that the rotation by the angle `theta` is done before `translate`, in the function `pressButtons`.

To solve your issue, create a global variable which notice the last pressed key and change the state of the variable in the function `pressButtons`

```java
char actKey = 0;
void pressButtons() {
    if (key == 'x' || key == 'X' || key == 'y' || key == 'Y' || key == 'z' || key == 'Z')
        actKey= key;
}
```

Create a new function, which performs the rotation, dependent on the state of `actKey`

```java
void addRotation() {
    if (actKey == 'x') { 
        theta = theta - .05;
        rotateX(theta);
    } else if (actKey == 'X') {
        theta = theta + .05;
        rotateX(theta);
    } else if (actKey == 'y') {
        theta = theta - .05;
        rotateY(theta);
    } else if (actKey == 'Y') {
        theta = theta + .05;
        rotateY(theta);
    } else if (actKey == 'z') {
        theta = theta - .05;
        rotateZ(theta);
    } else if (actKey == 'Z') {
        theta = theta + .05;
        rotateZ(theta);
    }
}
```

Perform the translation followed by the rotation at the begin of `cubeBox`:

```
void cubeBox(float x, float y, float z) {

    translate(x, y, z);
    addRotation();

    // [...]

}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! how do you pick for example red side and view it?

Comment: To make things clear each cube has a side. Choose a side for example Red side press 1 the cube will turn to that side, then 2 the yellow will appear on that  side of the cube.

Comment: Would you like to answer it pleases? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290954/processing-view-side-of-cube-when-pressing-key